OTtablx and linguex
I am trying to use linguex to number OT tables. But it does not work and I do not know why. Here is what I get by compiling the code provided below with the linguex command \ex. :
! LaTeX Error: \begin{tabular} on input line 14 ended by \end{list}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.

Code:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[noipa]{OTtablx}

\begin{document}

\ex.
\begin{OTtableau} [arabic] {4} 
\OTsolids{1,2} \OTtoprow [\normalfont \textit{Input}] {\textsc{\textbf{constraint 1}}, \textsc{\textbf{constraint 2}}, \textsc{\textbf{constraint 3}}} 
\OTcandrow {\normalfont candidate 1} {*!,,,} 
\OTcandrow {\OThand\normalfont candidate 2} {,*, *,} 

\end{OTtableau} 
\end{document}


cgloss is not a standard package in TeX Live. Where did you get it?

I don't understand. Is it that package that causes the issue? The thing is that even if I remove it, the problem is not solved.

I have just removed it and the command \ex.

Yes, that is what I am using.

I see. Maybe the package was updated ? It weird that the table cannot be numbered as any example.

Yes, that version has the bug fixed. My local version seems to have the bug.

My editor is Texmaker. About my Tex version, here is the information it shows when I compile something : This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (MiKTeX 23.10.12) (preloaded format=xelatex 2023.10.23) 23 JUL 2024 23:42

@SiluéLacina Your code got edited incorrectly by others and this removed the problem you were actually asking about. Your original posted example showed exactly the problem. Sorry for all the confusion. We've now put the original example back.

@AlanMunn Well, not exactly the original example because it doesn't fail due to the missing package.

Understood. Thanks.

The error you're getting is due to the fact the linguex example environment uses a blank line to delimit the end of an example. This means that when you use it with the OTtableau environment, that environment can't contain any blank lines or else they will be interpreted incorrectly as the end of the linguex example.  You have a blank line before the \end{OTtableau} line, and this is was giving you the error you see when embedded in linguex environment. There is no other problem embedding the tableau in a linguex example.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[noipa]{OTtablx}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
\ex.
\begin{OTtableau} [arabic] {4} 
\OTsolids{1,2} 
\OTtoprow [\normalfont \textit{Input}] {\textsc{\textbf{constraint 1}}, \textsc{\textbf{constraint 2}}, \textsc{\textbf{constraint 3}}} 
\OTcandrow {\normalfont candidate 1} {*!,,,} 
\OTcandrow {\OThand\normalfont candidate 2} {,*, *,} 
\end{OTtableau} 

\end{document}



Great ! Thanks. That solved the problem.

@SiluéLacina You can show the answer solved the issue by accepting it - there's a greyed-out tick thing at the top left of the answer. If you click on it, it turns green.
